# How does Facebook image compression and upload works

Tags: javascript, file-upload, image-compression

I am building photo compress and upload functionality like Facebook. . Is there any free java-script libraries available for doing similar functionality for photo upload.
Please advice.

Comment: I think facebook does image compression on client side and then uploads it to server making upload faster. Does facebook uses canvas element for compression ??

Answer (score 1):

Zstandard 1.0, developed by Yann Collet at Facebook. They have made it available with BSD license on Github. Here is the link [facebook/zstd](https://github.com/facebook/zstd). There are other compression mechanisms which are also present viz zlib, gzip, Zip etc. But according to facebook, zstd provides much better performance compared to zlib which is used traditionally.

If you need bindings in langauges other than C.
You will find the references on their [site](http://facebook.github.io/zstd/#other-languages).

You can read further details on this Facebooks engineering blog:
[Smaller and faster data compression with Zstandard](https://code.facebook.com/posts/1658392934479273/smaller-and-faster-data-compression-with-zstandard/)

Comment: Is it done on client side or the server side (once the image is uploaded to the server and compressed before the next request)?

Comment: There are few ports which are available on their official site. 
I suggest you have a look at this [facebook.github.io/zstd/#other-languages](https://facebook.github.io/zstd/#other-languages)

Answer (score 0):

J I C is a Javascript Image Compressor using HTML5 Canvas & File API that allows you to compress your jpeg & png images before uploading to the server (100% client-side and no extra libraries required!) Find the libary here [Github](https://github.com/brunobar79/J-I-C)